# Is boost::asio::io_service::post atomic?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, boost-asio, atomic

Given a `boost::asio::io_service io` is it safe to call `io.post(...)` on threads other than the thread that started `io.run()`?

For example:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;

void f()
{
    /* do something */
    io.post(&f);
}

void g()
{
    /* do something else */
    io.post(&g)
 }

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(&f);
    std::thread t2(&g);

    io.run();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I assume that `io_service` uses some kind of internal data structure (e.g. a queue) and posting alters this data structure (e.g. pushing onto the queue).  My concern is that the data structure may or may not be thread-safe.

I've searched around and haven't been able to find a straight answer to this question, although everything I've seen seems to indicate that `post()` is thread-safe (i.e. atomic).  Can someone please verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io_service::post` is thread_safe, and posting from different threads is just fine (one often needs to do it in a multithreaded asio environment).

However your example has a bit of a race condition:

`io.run()` might complete, before the child threads have started running, and therefore before anything gets posted.
If you want to avoid that it needs to run() until a specific stop condition (e.g. signaled from a posted handler) is met. `io_service::work` can help with that too.

Comment: Great.  Also, thanks for catching the bug in my code.